# combine the rows to file3 only if the date is present in both files in sorted order of dates and month

Tags: command-line, python3, csv

My problem is I need to consider the rows to file3 only if the date is present in both files

Consider file1.csv

```
dtime,c,y,s
2015-02-01,395,396,g
2015-02-02,395,397,g
2015-02-03,395,397,g
```

This file2.csv

```
dtime,c,y,s
2015-02-01,398,397,o
2015-02-03,399,397,o
```

Combine file3.csv should contain

```
dtime,c,y,s
2015-02-01,395,396,g
2015-02-01,398,397,o
2015-02-03,395,397,g
2015-02-03,399,397,o
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: script reads every line of file1.csv and if date found in file2.csv write both strings to file3.csv

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS="" read -r string1 || [ -n "$string1" ]
do
  date=$(cut -d',' -f1 <<< "$string1")
  string2=$(grep "$date" file2.csv)
  if [[ "$string2" ]]; then
    echo "$string1" >> file3.csv
    echo "$string2" >> file3.csv
  fi
done < file1.csv
```

Comment: it is just  giving the output as dtime,c,y,s after combining. The dates are not continued.

Comment: What you mean with "The dates are not continued."? I have run test on example files you provided, and get output as expected. Please explain whats wrong

Comment: It is working!. Thank You. Initially my raw data had time included which I need to strip. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are lexically ordered on the date field, you can use the `join` command - although it requires a bit of wrangling to get the desired output format:

Ex.

```
$ join --header -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,0,2.2,2.3,2.4 file1.csv file2.csv | 
    sed -e '1s/,dtime.*//' -e 's/,/\n/4'
dtime,c,y,s
2015-02-01,395,396,g
2015-02-01,398,397,o
2015-02-03,395,397,g
2015-02-03,399,397,o
```